# Counting Number of integer values using file positioning fucntion

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I have to write a below function:

**A function that returns the number of integers in a binary file of integers. Use file positioning functions, and do not read any of the integers.**

For this I tried doing as below but I found that when I use fseek() it will overwrite end of file character and thus my loop becomes infinite loop.

Could you please suggest what can be the way to count the integer values in a binary file using file positioning function.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    FILE *stream;
    int i=0, counter=0;

    stream = fopen("lab10binfile.dat","r");
    while(!feof(stream))
    {
        printf("Inside file");
        fseek(stream,sizeof(int)+i,SEEK_SET);
        counter++;
        i++;

    }
    printf("%d \n",counter);
}
```

The file has the following data :

262 259 266 603 82 46 813 92 44 481 110 542 690 798 277 
516 942 92 353 386 693 584 139 881 567 655 196 288 887 891 
425 871 635 516 222 205 590 329 193 956 276 248 729 355 974 
754 791

Comment: first, `fseek` does not set the `EOF`.

Comment: Okay. So which file positioning function can I use to count the number of values in a file

Comment: Is your file a text file or a binary file ?

Comment: Looks like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @MichaelWalz he said _in a binary file_.

Comment: It is a binary file. But I had a similar text file to check whether my function is returning correct values or not.

Comment: I am new to this C programming and I was asked to count the number of values in a file without reading any data.

Comment: @user3405771 If it's a binary file you should include a `"b"` in the mode string (i.e. `fopen("lab10binfile.dat","rb");`).

Comment: @user3405771: to me it sounds like if you just want to find out the size of the file.

Comment: and to try to find the size of the file in the fseek It is not a portable. I think a good way is to use the library to determine the file size of each implementation.、

Comment: I dont want to find the size of the file.

Comment: you want `(file size)/sizeof(int)`.

Comment: I just want to count the number of values in the file. If you can see the sample data of a file, it has 47 numbers. So I want the output from counter to be 47. Also I searched on web and found that fseek() will overwrite the end of file character and that is the reason why my while loop is becoming an infinite loop.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY according to the question's requirement I need to use file positioning function.

Comment: i said already finding the file size of the file positioning is not portable.

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not portable"

Comment: it is By `implementation-defined`.

Comment: _reason why_ : _After determining the new position, a successful call to the fseek function undoes any
effects of the ungetc function on the stream, clears the end-of-file indicator for the
stream, and then establishes the new position. After a successful fseek call, the next
operation on an update stream may be either input or output_ The fseek function 7.19.2-19

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a binary file, so you could simply divide the length of that file by the size of `int` to find out how many `int` it includes:

```
long
count(FILE *fp, size_t size)
{
    long end;

    if (fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END) < 0) {
        perror("fseek");
        return -1;
    }

    if ((end = ftell(fp)) < 0) {
        perror("ftell");
        return -1;
    }

    if (end % size != 0) {
        return -1;
    }

    return end / size;
}
```

---

Note: On POSIX system, `stat(2)` could also be used to find out the length of a file.

Comment: I ran this code, but I am still getting 0 as output. Do I need to keep something in mind?

Comment: @user3405771 What is the size of your data file? And what is the return value of my `count()` function?

Comment: How will I find that?

Comment: @user3405771 If you are using Unix-like system, such as Linux or Mac OS X, you could use `ls -l path_name` on terminal; if you are using Windows, you could ... Oh, I forget how to do it on Windows.

Comment: @user3405771: that code works fine here. Are you sure you open the correct file ? Are you sure that you display the returned value from the `count` function correctly. Have you tried using a debugger (you really should learn the basics of your debugger, it's a huge time saver). Show us your code using the `count` function that doesn'work.

Comment: Thank you all. I tried this `size_t size;
 fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_END);
 size = ftell(fptr);
 
 count = size/sizeof(int);` and it is working..